# Laravel Datatables - Invalid JSON response

Tags: laravel

I have the following which returns an **Invalid JSON response** while using Laravel Datatables.

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/products', 'ProductController@index')->name('products');
Route::get('/getproducts', 'ProductController@getProducts')->name('getProducts');'
```

**Controller**

```
public function index()
{   
    return view ('backend.products.home');
}

public function getProducts()
{
    return Datatables::of(Product::query())->make(true);
}
```

**View**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: '{!! route('getProducts') !!}',
      columns: [
        { data: 'product_name', name: 'product_name' },
        { data: 'manufacturer', name: 'manufacturer' },
        { data: 'price', name: 'price' },
       ]
   });
});
</script>
```

When I return `Datatables::of(Product::query())->make(true)` in the products view, I am getting the JSON like so:
[image]

Comment: What is invalid about that response?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 return Datatables::of(Product::query()->select('*'))->make(true);
```

Or:

```
return Datatables::of(Product::query()->get())->make(true);
```